# VirtualBox virtual machine - Debian stable (Lenny) has higher screen resolution than my monitor

Tags: debian, virtualbox

I installed debian in vm in virtualbox and it has 1280x1024 resolution, while physical screen is 1024x768... So I'm getting scrollable virtualbox window and I have to scroll it. It's pretty hard to work on it. I tried:

- Change resolution in gnome... There's no option to choose resolution (just window with blank buttons)
- Edit xorg.conf... xorg.conf is blank
- I googled and found out that it's normal for xorg.conf to be blank in this version and that I can use xrandr. I tried xrandr -s 1024x768... I got "size 1024x768 not found in available modes"
- sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg doesn't do anything. It only lets me to select keyboard layout and that's all. No xorg.conf is created.
- I turned off X and tried X -configure but I got completely blank black screen so I restarted vm. After restarting it I looked into xorg.conf and it's still blank.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem than you. I edited /etc/X11/xorg.conf with:

Section "Screen"
     Identifier  "Default Screen"
     Device      "Intel Corporation Mobile 915GM/GMS/910GML Express Graphics Controller"
     Monitor     "Monitor genérico"
     DefaultDepth    24
     SubSection "Display"
        Modes       "1024x768"
     EndSubSection
 EndSection

And restarted X server using CTRL+ALT+BackSpace (or from initial display botom).

The only one display conf that It works is 1024x768, when I'm using 1280x800 in windows XP. Now, when I select complete display in VirtualBox I get a nice display but black unused spaces on left and right.

Regards, fernando.

Comment: I edited my xorg.conf too and it works great !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply resizing the VirtualBox window? Worked for me with the VirtualBox drivers installed in the guest OS - changed the resolution to the size of the window.

Answer (score 0):

i installed the virtual box modules through the package manager in debian and that did the trick